# Two seemingly different totally ramified extension,$ \Bbb{Q}_p(ζ_{p^n})$ and $\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/n})$

Tags: field-theory, p-adic-number-theory, class-field-theory

$ \Bbb{Q}_p(ζ_{p^n})$ and $\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/n})$ are both totally ramified extension over $ \Bbb{Q}_p$ each has extension degree $p^n-p^{n-1}$ and $n$.

The former can be regarded as Lubin Tate extension, Frobenius power series $φ(X)＝(1＋X)^{p}-1$ gives the former Lubin Tate extension.

My question is, the latter does not come from Lubin Tate extension ?
Does anyone know some relation between these two fields ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $[\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/n}):\Bbb{Q}_p]=n$

Comment: And $\Bbb{Q}_p(p^{1/n})/\Bbb{Q}_p$ is abelian iff $n | p-1$ (or $n| 2$ if $p=2$)

Comment: They’re really as different as you can imagine two plausibly-similar extensions to be.   Best to take the phenomenon as a lesson in how messy wild ramification can be.